# Error Setting Up Angular/Components Dev Environment

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

I have installed dependencies successfully with Yarn. After running 'yarn dev-app' I get a long list of errors.

> ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/button/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:button-types/button-types-example.css'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/button/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:button-types/button-types-example.html'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/button/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:button-types/button-types-example.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/button/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target '//src/components-examples/material/button:index.ts' contains
> an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/button:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:bottom-sheet-harness/bottom-sheet-harness-example.html'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:bottom-sheet-harness/bottom-sheet-harness-example.spec.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:bottom-sheet-harness/bottom-sheet-harness-example.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:bottom-sheet-overview/bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:bottom-sheet-overview/bottom-sheet-overview-example.html'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:bottom-sheet-overview/bottom-sheet-overview-example.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet/BUILD.bazel:29:10:
> Target '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:index.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/bottom-sheet:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:badge-harness/badge-harness-example.html'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:badge-harness/badge-harness-example.spec.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:badge-harness/badge-harness-example.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:badge-overview/badge-overview-example.css'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:badge-overview/badge-overview-example.html'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:badge-overview/badge-overview-example.ts'
> contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/components-examples/material/badge/BUILD.bazel:28:10:
> Target '//src/components-examples/material/badge:index.ts' contains an
> error and its package is in error and referenced by
> '//src/components-examples/material/badge:source-files'

And some more:

> Analyzing: target //src/dev-app:devserver (0 packages loaded, 0
> targets configured) ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/core/BUILD.bazel:16:10:
> In rule 'core_tsec_test', size 'medium' is not a valid size. ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/core/BUILD.bazel:16:10:
> In rule 'core_tsec_test', timeout 'illegal' is not a valid timeout.
> ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/core/BUILD.bazel:140:18:
> In rule 'unit_tests_debug_bin', size 'medium' is not a valid size.
> ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/core/BUILD.bazel:140:18:
> In rule 'unit_tests_debug_bin', timeout 'illegal' is not a valid
> timeout. ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/core/BUILD.bazel:140:18:
> In rule 'unit_tests_debug', size 'medium' is not a valid size. ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/core/BUILD.bazel:140:18:
> In rule 'unit_tests_debug', timeout 'illegal' is not a valid timeout.
> ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/BUILD.bazel:12:11:
> In rule 'material_tsec_test', size 'medium' is not a valid size.
> ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material/BUILD.bazel:12:11:
> In rule 'material_tsec_test', timeout 'illegal' is not a valid
> timeout. ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material-experimental/BUILD.bazel:11:11:
> In rule 'material-experimental_tsec_test', size 'medium' is not a
> valid size. ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/material-experimental/BUILD.bazel:11:11:
> In rule 'material-experimental_tsec_test', timeout 'illegal' is not a
> valid timeout. ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/dev-app/BUILD.bazel:129:12:
> Target '//src/material:sass_lib' contains an error and its package is
> in error and referenced by '//src/dev-app:theme' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/dev-app/BUILD.bazel:129:12:
> Target '//src/material-experimental:sass_lib' contains an error and
> its package is in error and referenced by '//src/dev-app:theme' ERROR:
> C:/users/dell/desktop/personal/angular-material/components/src/dev-app/BUILD.bazel:129:12:
> Target '//src/material/core:theming_scss_lib' contains an error and
> its package is in error and referenced by '//src/dev-app:theme' ERROR:
> Analysis of target '//src/dev-app:devserver' failed; build aborted:

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Did you remember to import the modules for the components you are trying to use?
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#display-a-component

Comment: I am not using the @angular/material package on an Angular Project.  Trying to setup angular/components dev environment following :https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/DEV_ENVIRONMENT.md